# Transfer files from one OneDrive account to another OneDrive account?

Tags: office-365, onedrive

I need to transfer my OneDrive account from my former university to my new university. What tools are available to do this, or what is the process? I tried mover.io, but they charge $1/GB, and I have a few hundred GB of data.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use [mover.io](https://mover.io) - a recently Microsoft acquired service built for exactly this, therefore it's secure, tightly integrated and approved by Micrososft

I recently used it to transfer 108 GB of files from one account to another. It skipped around 10 GB for having long path names, all of which were saved in a log available for 90 days, in order for me to recheck them and transfer in another shorter path in those 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this: **[https://flow.microsoft.com/copy-files-from-one-onedrive-account-to-another](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/02f86638b67b464f913f282c3dc5a459/copy-files-from-one-onedrive-account-or-folder-to-another/)**

or you can put all data in one folder and then share it to yourself (to another account) and then retake ownership

Comment: How exactly do I retake ownership in my new account? I can only create a shareable link in OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Multcloud, it is an alternative to mover.io. It allows you to freely transfer files count 50GB/month. Since you have few hundred GB, you can migrate them separately in several months if you are not in a hurry. Or, you can order its monthly service (only $9.9 for 150GB/month) or Quarterly service (only $24.9 for 200GB/month). Guide for how to [transfer files from one OneDrive account to another OneDrive account](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/transfer-files-from-one-onedrive-account-to-another.html)